Connect a server peer (dynamic ip address) with browser peers javascript
I want to make live ip video calls between a python pyqt5 user and a browser (html5).
The javascript code i use for client is:
var port = 8080
var ip_address = "192.168.1.10"
var main_pc = {
    "name":"",
    "surname":"",
    "pc":null,
    "dc":null,
    "uid":null,
    "local_audio":null,
    "local_video":null,
    "remote_audio":null,
    "remote_video":null
};
var peer_connections = [];
var closing = false
var controller = null;
var signal;
var stop_time_out = null;

function start(name,surname) {
    $("#control_call_button").addClass("d-none");
    $("#stop_call_button").removeClass("d-none");
    
    $("#signal-audio").trigger("play");
    main_pc = createPeerConnection(main_pc);
    main_pc["name"] = name;
    main_pc["surname"] = surname;
    
    main_pc["dc"] = main_pc["pc"].createDataChannel('chat', {"ordered": true});
    
    main_pc["dc"].onmessage = function(evt) {
        data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        if(data["type"] == "closing"){
            if (main_pc["uid"] == "uid"){   
                stop_peer_connection();
            }else{
                //stop_client_peer_connection(data["uid"]);
            }
        }
        
        if (data["type"] == "uid"){
            uid = data["uid"];
            main_pc["uid"] = uid;
            console.log(main_pc);
        }
        
        if (data["type"] == "new-client"){
            var uid = data["uid"];
            var client_name = data["name"];
            var client_surname = data["surname"];
            console.log("New client:");
            console.log(uid);
            console.log(client_name);
            console.log(client_surname);
            //start_client(uid,client_name,client_surname);
        }
        
    };

    main_pc["pc"].onconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
       let newCS = main_pc["pc"].connectionState;
       if (newCS == "disconnected" || newCS == "failed" || newCS == "closed") {
            stop_time_out = setTimeout(stop_with_time_out, 7000);   
       }else{
            if (stop_time_out != null){
                clearTimeout(stop_time_out);
                stop_time_out = null;
            }
       }
    }

    
    main_pc["pc"].onclose = function() {
        closing = true;
        stop_peer_connection();
        
        // close data channel
        if (main_pc["dc"]) {
            main_pc["dc"].close();
        }

        // close local audio / video
        main_pc["pc"].getSenders().forEach(function(sender) {
            sender.track.stop();
        });

        // close transceivers
        if (main_pc["pc"].getTransceivers) {
            main_pc["pc"].getTransceivers().forEach(function(transceiver) {
                if (transceiver.stop) {
                    transceiver.stop();
                }
            });
        }
        main_pc["pc"] = null;
        $("#control_call_button").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#stop_call_button").addClass("d-none");
    };
    
    constraints = {audio:true,video:true};
    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            
            try {
                main_pc["pc"].addTrack(track, stream);
                if (track.kind == "video"){
                    //correct
                    main_pc["local_video"] = stream;
                    document.getElementById('client-video-1').srcObject = stream;
                }else{
                    main_pc["local_audio"] = stream;
                }
            } catch(e){
            }
        });
        return negotiate();
        }, function(err) {
            alert('Could not acquire media: ' + err);
    });
    
    
}

function createPeerConnection(pc) {
    var config = {
        sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan'
    };
    config.iceServers = [{ urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'] }];

    pc["pc"] = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

    // connect audio
    pc["pc"].addEventListener('track', function(evt) {
        if (evt.track.kind == 'audio'){
            $("#signal-audio").trigger("pause");
            $("#signal-audio").currentTime = 0; // Reset time
            document.getElementById('server-audio').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
            
            $("#control_call_button").addClass("d-none")
            $("#stop_call_button").removeClass("d-none")
            
            pc["remote_audio"] = evt.streams[0];
        }else if (evt.track.kind == 'video'){
            document.getElementById('server-video').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
            pc["remote_video"] = evt.streams[0];
        }
    });
    
    return pc;
}

function negotiate() {
    return main_pc["pc"].createOffer({"offerToReceiveAudio":true,"offerToReceiveVideo":true}).then(function(offer) {
        return main_pc["pc"].setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function() {
        // wait for ICE gathering to complete
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            if (main_pc["pc"].iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                function checkState() {
                    if (main_pc["pc"].iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                        main_pc["pc"].removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                main_pc["pc"].addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);

            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        var offer = main_pc["pc"].localDescription;
        controller = new AbortController();
        signal = controller.signal;
        try{
            promise = timeoutPromise(60000, fetch('http://'+ip_address+':'+port+'/offer', {
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    sdp: offer.sdp,
                    type: offer.type,
                    "name":name,
                    "surname":surname
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
                signal
            }));
            return promise;
        }catch (error){
            console.log(error);
            stop_peer_connection();
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok){
            return response.json();
        }else{
            stop_peer_connection();
        }
    }).then(function(answer) {
        console.log(answer);
        if (answer.sdp == "" && answer.type == ""){
            stop_peer_connection();
            return null;
        }else{
            return main_pc["pc"].setRemoteDescription(answer);
        }
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        stop_peer_connection();
        return null;
    });
    
}

function timeoutPromise(ms, promise) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error("promise timeout"))
    }, ms);
    promise.then(
      (res) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        resolve(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        reject(err);
      }
    );
  })
}

function stop_peer_connection(dc_message=true) {
    $("#signal-audio").trigger("pause");
    $("#signal-audio").currentTime = 0; // Reset time       
    // send disconnect message because iceconnectionstate slow to go in failed or in closed state
    try{
        if (main_pc["dc"].readyState == "open"){
            if (dc_message){
                main_pc["dc"].send(JSON.stringify({"type":"disconnected"}));
            }
        }
    }catch (e){
    }
    try{
        if (main_pc["local_audio"] != null){
            main_pc["local_audio"].getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
            main_pc["local_video"].getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
            main_pc["remote_audio"].getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
            main_pc["remote_video"].getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
            main_pc["local_audio"].stop();
            main_pc["local_video"].stop();
            main_pc["local_audio"] = null;
            main_pc["local_video"] = null;
            
            //main_pc["remote_audio"].stop();
            //main_pc["remote_video"].stop();
            //main_pc["remote_audio"] = null;
            //main_pc["remote_video"] = null;
        }
    }
    catch (e){
    }
    
    
    
    document.getElementById('client-video-1').srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById('server-video').srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById('server-audio').srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById('client-audio-2').srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById('client-video-2').srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById('client-audio-3').srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById('client-video-3').srcObject = null;

    try{
        if (controller != null){
            controller.abort();
        }
        if (main_pc["dc"].readyState != "open"){
            main_pc["pc"].close();
        }
    }catch (e){
    }
    $("#control_call_button").removeClass("d-none")
    $("#stop_call_button").addClass("d-none")
}

function stop_with_time_out(){
    stop_peer_connection(false);
    stop_time_out = null;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#control_call_button").on( "click", function() {
        name = $("#name").val();
        surname = $("#surname").val();
        $("#me-name").html(name+" "+surname)
        closing = false;
        controller = null;
        start(name,surname);
    });
    $("#stop_call_button").on( "click", function() {
        closing = true;
        stop_peer_connection();
    });
})

As you can see in the first two lines i declare the ip address of the server peer and the port the service will use.
But this ip is a local ip address.
I want when the python user opens the pyqt5 app then with requests module to populate the site with the new public address.
Then if it's possible i want the html5 user to connect with the python user without need of port forwarding (it's hard every time the user install the app the change the router settings). I suppose this will be done with ngrok python api.
Am i right?
Is there something i am missing?
Is there any alternative solution (tunelling) without cost and without need of port forwarding?

“Am i right?” Well, what happened when you tried it?

Try using something like PythonAnywhere to host a web server for free. You can also play around with ngrok, which lets you temporarily host your web server on the web for free. You can use the server to have both the browser and the PyQt5 app connect to it and have the server send stuff to either the browser or the PyQt5 app.
